# Splashscreen in cordova 4.3 error

Tags: android, cordova

I'm new in android develop . i tried to follow steps to create an android cordova splashscreen but I got this error :

```
CallbackContext cannot be resolved to a type    SplashScreen.java   

cordova cannot be resolved  SplashScreen.java   

preferences cannot be resolved  SplashScreen.java
```

Please Help .
Thanks

Comment: I google it but no idea found :(